Right bracket is not showing when equation breaker is used
I'm using a big equation. Hence, I used an equation breaker to break it. But I notice the right bracket are not showing anymore.
\begin{multline}%\begin{equation}
\label{eqn:eq0067}
 
d_{h}\left(G,P\right) \; {95\%}=max \left\{ \max\limits_{g \in G } \;  \min\limits_{p \in P } \; \vert \vert g - p \vert \vert_{2} \\ ,\max\limits_{ p \in P} \;  \min\limits_{g \in G } \;  \vert \vert g - p \vert \vert_{2}\right\}_{95\%}
\end{multline}%{equation} 



You do not show a complete example, but do you by any chance get an error message. If so, do not ignore it. Also, in LaTeX you shall not use empty lines in display environments.

also as you can see in your image, the first max should be \max

And, do please also replace all instances of \vert \vertwith \Vert.
